# Java reading and writing objects to files using UTF-8

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm creating a program that functions like a Japanese dictionary, so I'm needing to store Japanese word objects in a file. I'm currently trying to create a dat file that is unicoded, but I keep getting FileNotFound Exceptions. My main goal is being able to store my custom created word objects in a file that can store and read a object that contains Japanese text and a array of values. So if you know of anyway to solve this problem I would be very grateful!

This is my trial classes to test it out:

```
  public class JavaApplication1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//File file = new File("test.dat");
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,    ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    JavaApplication1 ja = new JavaApplication1();
    ja.start();
}
public void start() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    System.out.println("Enter Kanji");
    String Kanji = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Romanji");
    String Romanji = scan.next();
    System.out.println("How common is it");
    int common = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many types of word is it?");
    int loop = scan.nextInt();
    //List<int> typeOfWord = new ArrayList<int>();
    ArrayList type = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i<loop;i++){
        System.out.println("What type of word");
        type.add(scan.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println("What type of adjective");
    int adjective = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What type of verb");
    int verb = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many radicals");
    int loop2 = scan.nextInt();
     ArrayList radical = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i<loop2;i++){
        System.out.println("radical");
        radical.add(scan.nextInt());
    }
    Word word = new Word(Kanji,Romanji,common,type,adjective,verb,radical);
    store(word);
    //store(word);
    read();

}
public void store(Word word) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File file = new File("test.dat","UTF-8");
    FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outFileStream);
    oos.writeObject(word);
    oos.close();
}
public void read() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    File file = new File("test.dat");
    FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(filein);
    Word word = (Word)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    word.getKanaKanji();
}
}
```

This is the class that I'm using to get my values for my Word object, and this is my word class:

```
  public Word(){

}
public Word(String kanaKanji, String romanji, int commonType, ArrayList wordTypeList,
        int adjectiveType, int verbType, ArrayList radicalList){
    this.wordTypeList = wordTypeList;
    this.radicalList = radicalList;
    this.adjectiveType = adjectiveType;
    this.commonType = commonType;
    this.verbType = verbType;
    this.kanaKanji = kanaKanji;
    this.romanji = romanji;

}
//slew of get methods
public String getKanaKanji(){
 return kanaKanji;   
}
public String getRomanji(){
    return romanji;
}
public StringBuilder getDefinition(){
    int size = definitionList.size();
    StringBuilder definitions = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i <definitionList.size();i++){
        definitions.append((i+1)+"."+definitionList.indexOf(i) +"\n");
    }
    return definitions;
}
}
```

From these two classes I want to store and read the created word object in a file, but I can't figure out the most convenient way.

Comment: you get `FileNotFoundExceptions`because your files does not exist! Are you invocking the method `read` before `write`? If you create an empty file in the project directoty?

Comment: You need to explain what line is throwing the exception. Also, Unicode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: show us the complete stack trace, and you will see that the application is searching the file in another directory

Comment: @fGo why would it be searching the file in a directory different than the one it creates the file in?

Comment: @Martinho if it invokes read before store

Comment: The code posted doesn't.

Comment: You'll probably want to store a data structure of some kind, like a `HashMap`, that will allow you to keep a whole dictionary in one file.

Comment: @Martinho Then how is he/she getting that exception? Maybe thats not even his/her last version of the code

Comment: Yeah, I've tried creating a blank file in the directory and I've tried creating it during the run of the program, but I keep getting that error. When I don't include the UTF-8 conversion it works fine, but I think I need to convert it since I have an object that has a Japanese text included in it.

Comment: Read the second answer, i think it should be enought

Comment: The only "UTF-8" in evidence here is in the *name* of the output file. You aren't using any UTF-8 encoding; you are using Java Object Serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
File file = new File("test.dat","UTF-8");
```

should simply be

```
File file = new File("test.dat");
```

The file is binary (the Java object).
Internal Strings will be kept in Unicode - no problem there.

`new File(("test.dat","UTF-8");` in fact is `new File("test.dat/UTF-8")` and expecting a directory `test.dat`. Hence FileNotFound. See [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks @fGo, yes I now added the needed clarification.

Comment: i didn't spot that! my respect to you sir :) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.io.File, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use existing means of object (de)serialisation like XML or JSON.
Or even the use of a database.

You could then utilize already existing big frameworks, if you want to extend you program e. g. with a search function etc.

---

Here you have an [example with JAXB](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html).